# Batch renaming files in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, vector, batch-rename

I have a directory with thousands of files, and I would like to rename a subset of these files.

Here's a highly simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
    library(dplyr)    
    f <- as.data.frame(list.files(), header=FALSE)
    colnames(f) <- 'origFilename'
    f2 <- f %>% separate(origFilename, into=c('ID','date','channel','position','extension'), sep='_', remove=FALSE) 
        %>% filter(ID > 10)
    f2$ID <- as.numeric(f2$ID)
    f3 <- f2 %>% mutate(newID = ID + 1)
    f3$newFilename <- paste(f3$newID, f3$date, f3$channel, f3$position, 
    f3$extension, sep='_')
    f3$origFilename <- paste(f3$ID, f3$date, f3$channel, f3$position, f3$extension, sep='_')
    file.rename(f3$origFilename, f3$newFilename)
```

The last line of this code gives the following error:

> Error in file.rename(f$files.old, f$files.new) :    invalid 'from'
>   argument

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Sorry, I'm not sure how to make a fully reproducible example here...

Comment: `file.rename(list.files(), paste(list.files(), "foo", sep="_"))`

Comment: Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This may help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
f <- as.data.frame(list.files(), header=FALSE)
colnames(f) <- 'files.old'
#"foo" will be added just before the extension
f$files.new <- sapply(f$files.old,function(x) gsub("^[^.]*.",paste(gsub(".[^.]*$", "", x), 'foo.', sep='_'),x))
file.rename(as.vector(f$files.old), as.vector(f$files.new))
```

Comment: this worked! I just needed to add the `as.vector`s.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is `as.data.frame`; `file.rename()` gets lists as inputs.

You can simply do it like this:

```
file.rename(list.files(), paste(list.files(), "foo", sep="_"))
```

But problem with doing so is that you make the extension of files to be altered. Above would change `mycode.r` to `mycode.r_foo` which then cannot be opened by R.

Comment: The changes that I'm making to the filenames are actually much more complicated (and also don't result in altering the file extension - sorry for the silly example), so this solution doesn't really work for me. Furthermore, I'm only trying to change a subset of all the files in the directory, so putting `list.files()` doesn't work. I'll make some edits to my question to clarify.